# How to fetch corresponding data for multiple inputs in SQL as IN clause returns all possible records instead of corresponding records

Tags: java, sql

Consider this scenario.

Table structure:(sample)

```
Id  grpnumber  subject  mark
1.  101.            Eng.       88
1.  101.            math.     93
2.   102.           Eng.        76
2.   102.           Math.     83
```

And the query:

```
Select *
from Records
where studentId IN (1,2) AND
      grpumber IN (101,102) AND
      subject IN('eng','math').
```

Above query returns four rows as it returns marks of two subjects for both students but I need eng subject mark for 1st (id=1) student and math mark for second student(Id=2). How to write query for this.

P.S: I passing those inputs ( n number of inputs)dynamically in prepared statement.

Comment: Same Id for different courses? How come?

Comment: @jarlh here we have multiple rows for sameId but only difference is subject in each row.(And this is sample scenario as I am mimicking the actual concept)

Comment: Can you specify the expected result-set as well.

Comment: yeah, multiple rows for same id but the difference is Subject. (this is sample scenario actually mimicking the actual one). you can consider subject code instead of subject(for eg Eng-001, math-002) and unique key is the combination of studentid+grpnumber+subjectcode- so could be like 1+101+001.(1101001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem I believe what you are looking for is to parametize your query. Here is a possible solution. Since I didn't have any DDL or data, I provided my own.
 Table as I see it.

```
  CREATE TABLE sample (
    id          NUMBER,
    grpnumber   NUMBER,
    subject     VARCHAR2(255),
    mark        NUMBER
);
```

Data in table.

```
REM INSERTING into SAMPLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into SAMPLE (ID,GRPNUMBER,SUBJECT,MARK) values (1,101,'Eng',88);
Insert into SAMPLE (ID,GRPNUMBER,SUBJECT,MARK) values (1,101,'Math',93);
Insert into SAMPLE (ID,GRPNUMBER,SUBJECT,MARK) values (2,102,'Eng',76);
Insert into SAMPLE (ID,GRPNUMBER,SUBJECT,MARK) values (2,102,'Math',83);
```

potential query using bind variables to

```
SELECT
    id studentid,
    grpnumber,
    lower(subject) subject,
    mark
FROM
    sample s
WHERE (s.id = :id1  AND lower(subject) = 'eng') OR
      (s.id = :id2 AND lower(subject)  = 'math')
```

Values provided to bind variables are .

```
:id2 = 1
:id1 = 2
```

results:

```
"STUDENTID" "GRPNUMBER" "SUBJECT"   "MARK"
       1      101        "math"       93
       2      102         "eng"       76
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I understand. But this select query fetch one record, how we can fetch records for multiple id in same query. For example I need studentId '2' with grp number 102  'math' mark too.

Comment: are you doing this in java and are you using any library like spring jdbc? or are you just using straight up jdbc? Is the real question you have that you want to pass the values into the `in` dynamically like a comma separated string?

Comment: I m using spring jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new preparedStatement, beanRowMapper). new preparedStatement is where I m dynamically passing comma separated values in IN clause. Currently my query has IN clause for 3 columns ( the same query I mentioned in question) but the IN clause for subject column in query causing issue, instead of fetching one subject for corresponding studentId it fetching records for all subject which comes in IN clause for single student ID.The resultSet I would expect for query mentioned in ques is two rows that is 1st row and 4 th row mentioned in table structure(in ques)

Comment: Ok according to your response I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the query would look like this

```
where (studentId = 1 AND subject = 'eng') OR
      (studentId = 2 AND subject = 'math')
```

How to make this dynamic really depends on what and how should be dynamic...